# Prove that $f = \sqrt{|x||y|}$ is not holomorphic at origin

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm doing this problem on Stein.

> Prove that $f = \sqrt{|x||y|}$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ is not holomorphic at origin but satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann Equation at $0$.

Write $f = u + iv$. I calculated the derivative at $0$ for $u(x, y) = \sqrt{|x||y|}$ and got:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{|y|}{|x|}}$ (deepening on the signs of $x$), and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0$ since $f$ is real (thus $v$) is real. So I cannot show that $f$ satisfies the CR at $0$. Am I missing something?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,0)&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{u(h,0)-u(0,0)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{0-0}{h}\\
&=0,
\end{align*}
similar for $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$, so the Cauchy-Riemann condition holds.